# How can i get "Other User" Tab as selected from all user tab in switch user page using autoit

Tags: autoit

I want to remotely access my desktop by clicking "Other User" tab from all the user tab in the login screen. Please suggest the commands for getting the  " other user" tab[image] as selected using autoit.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you [cannot do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901298/to-check-and-log-in-windows-from-autoit-script). The Windows login/unlock screen is secured and cannot be reached.